# Cannot unionise tow datasets

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

In Google Cloud Dataprep, when altering the recipe of a dataset to unionise another set with it in my flow, I get the error message: "Cannot read property `expandScriptLines`of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You may find these articles useful if you are running Cloud Dataprep by TRIFACTA® INC. in the Google Cloud Platform (my assumption, based off your post):

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Using-BigQuery_59736092

https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005jo8atSAA/the-chosen-settings-are-invalid-cannot-read-property-projectid-of-undefined

> Essentially, it is caused by the limitation of Dataprep to read a projectID that contains more than one ":"
>
> The development team is currently looking at implementing a fix.
>
> The current workaround is to ensure that the project ID does not contain more than one ":" or else, point to another Project that contains one or less ":" in its project ID.